# SuspiciousFileOperation when uploading picture

Tags: python, django, dropbox

I try to upload a picture in django admin panel, without success. I made a minimal app with basic information, but it fails when I want to upload the ImageField to the server (storage on Dropbox). I installed `django-storages`, and here are my settings :

```py
DROPBOX_OAUTH2_TOKEN = "my_token_here"
DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH    = 'storage'
```

My model :

```py
class Picture(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='', blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I get the following error :

```
SuspiciousFileOperation at /
Detected path traversal attempt in '/home/me/Code/my-project/storage/my_image.JPG'

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/gallery/picture/add/

Django Version: 4.0.2
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'gallery']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 622, in wrapper
    return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 236, in inner
    return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1670, in add_view
    return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 43, in _wrapper
    return bound_method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 130, in _wrapped_view
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1549, in changeform_view
    return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1599, in _changeform_view
    self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1108, in save_model
    obj.save()
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 743, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 780, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 885, in _save_table
    results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 923, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert(
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1301, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1440, in execute_sql
    for sql, params in self.as_sql():
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1382, in as_sql
    value_rows = [
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1383, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1383, in <listcomp>
    [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1334, in pre_save_val
    return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 302, in pre_save
    file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 89, in save
    self.name = self.storage.save(name, content, max_length=self.field.max_length)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 56, in save
    validate_file_name(name, allow_relative_path=True)
  File "/home/me/Code/my-project/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/utils.py", line 18, in validate_file_name
    raise SuspiciousFileOperation(

Exception Type: SuspiciousFileOperation at /admin/gallery/picture/add/
Exception Value: Detected path traversal attempt in '/home/me/Code/my-project/patrimoine/storage/2020-4-3-IMG_7410.JPG'
```

I searched for this error on the web and found that it has something to do with relative/absolute paths, but didn't find a way to fix it. I tried to change `DROPBOX_ROOT_PATH` from `'/storage'`, to `''`, but it didn't change anything.

I have to say that the pictures are uploaded to my *Dropbox*, but the model objects are not created.

EDIT: I found [this post](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/1109) on `django-storage` repository, it seems like this issue occurs because Dropbox gets Full Path as a name but django needs only `filename+extension` (credit to @churongcon). There is no workaround for now it seems.

Answer (score -1):

Add `storages` to **`INSTALLED_APPS`**. Then add the following code snippet to `settings.py`:

```py
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE='storages.backends.dropbox.DropBoxStorage'
```